# Excel VBA: If Equal Not to, then show error message

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

Can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

I have a code where I need to check if in certain sheet can be found certain products' ID before making an order.

```
Private Sub Pardot_Click()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToFind As String

valueToFind = pardID
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Noliktava")
Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A500")

For Each xlCell In xlRange
    If xlCell.Value <> valueToFind Then
        MsgBox ("This product wasn't found in the database - ID: " & pardID.Text)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next xlCell
```

End Sub

Basically, I launch the userform and type in the ID (i.e. 1) in the box and click "Okay" or whatever, if the ID can't be found in the range (ID:1) I want it to show the error Msg.

Code works if I change <> to =, but that's not the needed result.

Comment: `valueToFind` is a String (text) value and I assume that the column A consists of numbers. Either you change both to text or both to numbers using `CStr()` or `CLng()` or `CDbl()` etc. before comparing the values.

Comment: Try Trim and ubound using the =.  If there is a space at the end of one and not the other it will fail.

Comment: Glad my answer helped, but for your own knowledge, I recommend also reviewing @Ralph's comment. No doubt sometime in the future you'll want to compare a string to number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing your code too much, and probably saving some time, instead of checking each cell in the range, just use CountIf()?

```
Private Sub Pardot_Click()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToFind As String

valueToFind = pardID
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Noliktava")
Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A500")

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(xlRange,valuetoFind) = 0 then 
    msgbox "This product wasn't found in the database - ID: " & parId.textEnd 
End If

End Sub
```

Note: this will look for ***exactly*** the text the user inserted.  Use wildcards if it can be somewhere in a string (i.e. search for "dog" in "doggone", "dog food","dog")

Comment: Thank you, BruceWayne. Works.